# How to test POST spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

My problem is to how to call this. I could do

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
myController.save(o, "value");
```

but this is not what I would like to do. I would like the MyObject to be in the request post body? How can this be done?

```
@Requestmapping(value="/save/{value}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void post(@Valid MyObject o, @PathVariable String value{
    objectService.save(o);
}
```

Just to be clear I am talking about unit testing.

Edit:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public View postUser(ModelMap data, @Valid Profile profile, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        return dummyDataView;
    }


    data.put(DummyDataView.DATA_TO_SEND, "users/user-1.json");
    profileService.save(profile);
    return dummyDataView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See sample code below that demonstrates unit testing a controller using junit and spring-test.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:rest.xml"
    })
public class ControllerTest{
    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;



    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        this.request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.setContentType("application/json");
        this.response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPost(){
        request.setMethod("POST");
        request.setRequestURI("/save/test");  //replace test with any value

        final ModelAndView mav;
        Object handler;

        try{
                MyObject o = new MyObject();
                //set values
                //Assuming the controller consumes json
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                //set o converted as JSON to the request body
                //request.setContent(mapper.writeValueAsString(o).getBytes());
                request.setAttribute("attribute_name", o); //in case you are trying to set a model attribute. 
                handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
                mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, handler);
                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
                //Assert other conditions.
            }
        catch (Exception e) 
            {

            } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Must it json? Must I use the requestbody?

Comment: It can be converted in to any type that your controller accepts. Form the data, get the bytes and set it to the request.

Comment: So I could do  request.setContent(o); ?

Comment: You need to convert o to one of the types of messages that the controller accepts. What is the message type that the controller accepts? Like JSON/XML ?

Comment: If you are trying to accept model attributes, the controller needs to be modified like (@ModelAttribute("myobject") MyObject o, @PathVariable String value) and then in the unit test you can set MyObject as a parameter like request.setAttribute("myobject", o) .

Comment: I am able to pass an object but the attributes in the object are null even if i set them in the test method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RequestBody:

```
@Requestmapping(value="/save/{value}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void post(@RequestBody MyObject o, @PathVariable String value{
   objectService.save(o);
}
```

general info about request body documentation : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody

Comment: Ok.. maybe..but pretend that I am using it. How do I unit test this?